# Rails, user triggered ajax calls and options for html output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery

i'm making user triggered (jquery click) ajax call to load extra data to fill the web page, what's the correct way to build the html: should I generate the html within the rails controller and just return html data, or should i return JSON and build it in ajax function? Or are there some better ways to make ajax calls in rails?

Here is the countries.html.haml code at the moment (html data generated in controller):

```
$('#tab li').click( function(){
  $('#tab li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var first_l = $(this).attr("id")

  $.ajax({
    url: "/countries/get_flags",
    type: "GET",
    data: {first_letter: first_l},
    complete: function() {
      // called when complete
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // called when succesful
      $('#countries_container').html("");
      $('#countries_container').append(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error) {
      // called when error
    }
  });
});
```

And the controller:

```
def get_flags

  @html = ""
  @fetched_countries = Country.all( :conditions => "name like '#{params[:first_letter]}%'")
  i = 1
  @html = "<div class='row country-row'>"
  @fetched_countries.each do |country|
    if i % 5 == 0
      @html += "<div class='row country-row'>"
      i = 1
    end

    @html += "<div class='span3 '>"
    @html += "<div class='country-name'>#{country.name}</div>"
    @html += "<div class='country-image thumbnail'><img  alt='#{country.id.to_s}' src='/assets/countries/x100/#{country.id.to_s}.png' /></div></div>"
    if i % 4 == 0
      @html += "</div>"
    end
    i = i + 1

  end
  render :text => @html

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  the most natural place to put complex HTML generation code is in a Helper.  Normally helpers are utilized from within view code.  They are included in the view code  by virtue the helper method.  But if you find the need to generate HTML code in the controller,  you can use the helper code and return the HTML to the browser from the controller.

To directly answer the question,  I would recommend to generate the HTML in your controller instead of trying to build it using JavaScript in the browser.  When you are using Rails and Javascript,  rails is a more robust environment than JavaScript in the browser, it just makes sense to keep as much of your development effort focused in the more comprehensive environment.

As a BONUS answer,  If you find your self building lots of complex HTML code within helpers,  you may want to look at Builder::XmlMarkup,  ESPECIALLY if you come from a C/C++ background.  Builder::XmlMarkup allows you to create HTML in a way that's very intuitive to a C programmer.  Even if you don't come from C/C++,  Builder::XmlMarkup results in very readable code,  for example:

```
require 'active_support/builder' unless defined?(Builder)  

def an_html_generator_method(somestuff)
  xm = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
  xm.div(:class=>'mydiv') {
    xm.ul(:id=>'aMenu') {
      somestuff.each do |i|
        xm.li { xm << i.whatever }
      end
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: Such an awesome answer! Thank you very much! I'll definitely look into that class.